# MyBatis Parameter Not Found

Tags: java, spring-mybatis

I'm triying to calling a rest application but I get a 500 error. The problem maybe be on the MyBatis call but still can't fix it.

This is where I call the execution of MyBatis

```
@Override
public List<IdentitatBDTO> searchIdentitatsRepresentantsByRelacioIdentitatRepresentat(final String representatIdentificador, final Date dateFi) {

    List<Identitat> identitats = myBatisTemplate.execute(RelacioDao.class, new MyBatisDaoCallback<List<Identitat>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Identitat> execute(MyBatisDao dao) {
            return ((RelacioDao) dao).searchIdentitatsRepresentantsByRelacioIdentitatRepresentat(representatIdentificador, dateFi);
        }
    });
```

The error that I'm getting is

```
{
"errorUrl": 
 "http://localhost:8080/idjrepresentaciorest/rest/representacio/representants/12340002L",
  "errorMessage": "\r\n### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'representatIdentificador' not found. Available parameters are [1, 0, param1, param2]\r\n### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'representatIdentificador' not found. Available parameters are [1, 0, param1, param2]",
  "errorStackTrace": "org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: \r\n### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'representatIdentificador' not found. Available parameters are [1, 0, param1, param2]\r\n### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'representatIdentificador' not found. Available parameters are [1, 0, param1, param2]\r\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)\r\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:150)\r\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)\r\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:137)\r\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:75)\r\n\tat org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.searchIdentitatsRepresentantsByRelacioIdentitatRepresentat(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat es.bcn.idj.representaciorest.business.impl.RelacioServiceImpl$1.execute(RelacioServiceImpl.java:61)\r\n\tat es.bcn.idj.representaciorest.business.impl.RelacioServiceImpl$1.execute(RelacioServiceImpl.java:1)\r\n\tat net.opentrends.openframe.services.persistence.mybatis.template.impl.MyBatisTemplateImpl.execute(MyBatisTemplateImpl.java:64)\r\n\tat
```

But I debugged and saw that the variable that appears to be the problem is filled correctly so why is MyBatis not founding the variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Param annotation has two, one belongs to spring, one belongs to mybatis.Their usage is different.

- **org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param**

  ```
  User getUserById(@Param("id") Integer id);
  <select id="getUserById" resultMap="userMap">
      select name,age
      from user
      where id=#{0, jdbcType=INTEGER}
  <select/>
  ```

  It's based on the order of the parameters, and starts from 0.

---

- **org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param**

  ```
  User getUserById(@Param("id") Integer id);
  <select id="getUserById" resultMap="userMap">
      select name,age
      from user
      where id=#{id, jdbcType=INTEGER}
  <select/>
  ```

  Is based on the parameter name.

---

So, check that the annotations you introduced in mapper.java are consistent with the usage in mapper.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether value that is subject to some condition in Mybatis are sent from the Mapper class.
I was facing the same issue due to this code

```
<if test="fruit != null">
    and table.fruit_name = #{fruit}
</if>
```

The problem was I hadn't sent fruit from Mapper Class.
Adding `@Param("fruit")` in the mapper class fixed the issue for me.